# Handle multiple button click listeners

Tags: android, button, listener

I've two ImageButtons in my layout, "plus" and "minus". 
I attach a click listener to the "plus" button with a simple toast message in the click function, and it works.

```
    ImageButton btplus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btplus);        
    btplus.setOnClickListener( new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
```

Then i attach a second click listener to the minus ImageButton...

```
    ImageButton btminus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btminus);
    btminus.setOnClickListener( new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
```

...and no more button click works! The "plus" click too stop working.

I've seen a lot of examples on this theme, but i can't see any difference between them (working) and mine.

Comment: just change ImageButton.onClickListener() to View.onClickListener() and also add .show() at the end of toast method. Like = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @ChiragRaval You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Audrius Thanks for your comments. I think if any question is solved by just adding simple comments then there is no need to post answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 ImageButton btplus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btplus);        
    btplus.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

Such as multiple button click listners...

```
 ImageButton btminus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btminus);
 btminus.setOnClickListener(this);

 ImageButton btplus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btplus);
 btplus.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then your activity want to implements onclicklistener and you get implemented method is:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btplus:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plus is clicked" + "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            break;
        case R.id.btminus:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Minus is clicked" + "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i know this approach but i prefer to keep separate functions: i only need that ".show()"

Answer (score 1):

> Registered onClick event in the XML layout and then handle it in the code. This is how I would do it:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btplus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me"
android:onClick="onBtnClicked">
</Button>
```

Method in .class

```
 public void onBtnClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btplus:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plus is clicked" + "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            break;
        case R.id.btminus:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Minus is clicked" + "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```